# React. this.props.children is undefined for component with nested subcomponents

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-component

I am newcomer with React and could not handle this error. I have two components
the first one (routing):

```
var App = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
   return (
    <Template>
      <Locations>
        <Location path="/" handler={Catalog} />
        <Location path="/item/:item" handler={CatalogDetail} />
      </Locations>
    </Template>
   );
  }
});
```

and second one:

```
var Template = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        {this.props.children} // should render one of child components
                              //{catalog}/{catalogDetail}
      </div>
    )
  }
});
```

*this.props.children* is undefined and I could not understand why is not seeing one of these components {Catalog} or {CatalogDetail}

Comment: I don't see Catalog or CatalogDetail defined anywhere.

Comment: They are defined into "App" component (these components work as expected))

Comment: What component is "the second one"?

Comment: Second is "Template", first is "App"

Comment: Are you attempting to use `react-router` or `react-router-component`? This doesn't seem to be the way you would set up `react-router`.

Comment: I am using `react-router-component`. I have required it within "App" component: `var Router = require('react-router-component');`
`var Locations = Router.Locations;`
`var Location  = Router.Location;`